# Array filling function return nothing

Tags: python-3.x

I have an issue im beginner and looking my code for a while but cant find the answer why my prog return nothing with this function

```
def num_list(mylist):
y=int(input("Hany szamot szeretnel megadni: "))
x=0
mylist=[]
while x<y:
    mylist.append(int(input("szam: ")))
    x=x+1
return mylist


numbers=[]
num_list(numbers)<-- this is how i try to fill
```

and after i print it it says its empty ( [])

Comment: i found the answer as just def num_list()

Comment: another answer is i dont need mylist=[] cuz its zero it out, as number defined below its know its array so it was the mayor issue the way i tryed to do